# Webform-Civicrm issue on iPhone and Safari Browser

Tags: webform-civicrm

I created a simple webform with contribution form integration.

The form will not submit on Safari Browsers and on iPhones regardless whether they are using Chrome or Safari.

Instead of submited the form is reloaded. This only happens when payments are being submitted.

I've addressed all js errors and error still persists.

Using civicrm 5.10.4, webform 4.18 & webform_civicrm 4.26

Comment: Hi Yossi - I just tested this on one of my webform civicrm project sites and this is working fine. I tested on 5.7.4 as most of our clients are on ESR. When you say 'Error still persists' what error did you find?

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT What I meant was that the faulty behavior persists. I don't see any errors though. You can test on this form https://newsite.chabadsuite.net/content/test-form. CC# 4242424242424242

Comment: What Payment Processor do you use?

Comment: Usually Authorize.net or Stripe but this form is setup with the dummy payment processor

Comment: Have you tried swapping your theme to e.g. something boring like Bartik? Sometimes special mobile CSS and JS can kick in and interfere.

Comment: Good idea. I Just changed to bartik. Didn't help. :(

Comment: Do you have another site you can try reproduce this on?

Comment: newsite.chabadsuite.net/content/test-form this is a new site I created just to replicate the issue. This is not the original form where I found the error

Comment: But same environment?

Comment: Yes... I will replicate on different env.

Comment: Have you confirmed this is only an issue with civicrm webforms and not standard drupal web forms?

Comment: @petednz afaik the issue only happens when a contribution page is enabled. Form without payment options seen to work fine

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Just created a form on a completely different env. http://dev-democs.chabadsuite.com/content/test-form - Issue is still there

Comment: That does not sound completely different. I can’t reproduce this - so how did you find out? Was your existing form working and then after an upgrade (which) it stopped working?

Comment: It's stil civicrm and drupal but this new one I just posted is on Pantheon. I created a new form and users were complaining that it wouldn't work on iPhone. You created a new webform and enabled payment via cc and it worked? Can I try

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT

Comment: I’ve got dozens of clients using webform civicrm to process monies (with iATS Payments) and I made a donation on my phone for one of them - I can not reproduce the issue - it’s working fine.

Comment: Are they using webform-CiviCRM 4.26? Did you use an iPhone?

Comment: I've also checked this (albeit on CiviCRM 5.7.5, webform 4.19, webform Civi 4.26) on a form using Stripe using an iPhone and no difficulties whatsoever.  Have you checked with Pantheon to see whether there's something in their settings causing an issue?

Comment: Like Lesley said - we are not seeing any problems across any of our clients.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem specific to Stripe and Webform. I opened an [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/issues/42) on Gitlab.